# SSH on Cloud routers

Tags: ssh

I have a Cloud router (cisco CSR router) and want to access the Cloud router through SSH . Is there a way to re-establish the SSH connection after the router is reloaded .  What are all the options available

Comment: I don't quite get your question here. You want to automatically reconnect the SSH as soon the router is available again and you don't want to retype the command but rather have something retry it until it connects again?

Comment: Yes , basically I need to access the cloud router through SSH. After performing some tests , I need to reload the router . Now the interface through which the SSH connection is established earlier goes down . AS a result I will not be able to access the router again . Other option is to use telnet , but would prefer to use SSH ,

Comment: You gotta clarify a little more. The connection will always close when it has nothing to connect to. You will always have to reconnect if you reboot one machine. Can't keep something open which doesn't exist. If I'm wrong correct me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retry the SSH connection without retyping the command try something like a loop command

`until ssh command here; do sleep 5; done`

This should retry your SSH command until it succeeds with 5 seconds delays between each attempt.